# Export ASPxGridView to xlsx using ASPxGridViewExporter with formatted text

Tags: asp.net, excel, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an `ASPxGridView` having a number of columns (of type `GridViewDataComboBoxColumn` or `GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn`). In the code behind in the grid's `CustomColumnDisplayText` event I format the text of the cells in the following way:

```
protected void MyGrid_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column is DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewDataColumn)
    {
        switch (e.Column.FieldName)
        {
            case "Energy":
                if (e.Value is float)
                {
                    // the FormatEnergy method here returns for example "323.32 kWh"
                    e.DisplayText = DataDisplayTools.Instance.FormatEnergy((float)e.Value);
                }
                break;

                // other cases

        }
    }
}
```

For exporting the grid view in *.xlsx* format I use an `ASPxGridViewExporter`:

```
protected void lnkXlsxExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        gridViewExporter.DataBind();
        gridViewExporter.WriteXlsxToResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I export the grid view to *.xlsx*, the values of the columns in the exported file are not formatted as they are in the grid view.
For example the values in the grid view (they are formatted in the `CustomColumnDisplayText` event) are

- 32,332 kWh
- 311 kWh
- 2,254 kWh

but these values in the *xlsx* file after exporting appear like

- 32332
- 311
- 2254

[image]

My question is: Can export an `ASPxGridView` to an excel file having exactly the same texts in the excel file's cells as the grid view has, using an `ASPxGridViewExporter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASPxGridViewExporter exports the grid content by values, not display text. Create an instance of the [XlsxExportOptions](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingXlsxExportOptionsMembersTopicAll) class, set its [TextExportMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingXlsExportOptionsBase_TextExportModetopic) property to Text, and use this instance during exporting. Here is a corresponding ticket on DevExpress Support Center: [ASPxGridView - The CustomColumnDisplayText event doesn't not work when exporting to Excel after upgrading from v.9.2 to v.13.2](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T129194).

You may also face a problem described in the [ASPxGridView / MVC GridView Extension - Excel Data Aware Export FAQ](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T186064) ticket. This ticket provides a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkXlsxExport" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Please, provide an explanation about what your solution is supposed to do and why